# Procedure of leaving South Korea after overstaying your visa

Tags: us-citizens, tourist-visas, overstaying, south-korea

What is the procedure of leaving South Korea after overstaying my visa? Specifically, what happens when i visit the Korea Immigration Service Center (KIS) after almost 6 months in the country?

---

Almost 6 months now in South Korea. Tourist visa and I’m a US citizen

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the length of the overstay, there could be fines, and detention. Plus of course you'll be sent back to the US – and they'll try their damnedest to make you foot the bill. There will probably be an entry ban too, again, depending on the length of the overstay.

If you have some money, you might want to contact a lawyer and go together to Mokdong. KIS officers are unpleasant even in the best of cases. With you, they're going to be VERY unpleasant.